# A question about higher order tensor notations and symmetric group action

Tags: group-theory, permutations, tensors, group-actions, symmetric-groups

Reading the following poster https://haggaim.github.io/projects/universality/poster.pdf

A *higher order* tensor is defined as $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n^k \times a}$ and given a group $G$, its action on $X$ is defined as

$$(g \cdot X)_{i_1, \dots, i_k,j} = X_{g^{-1}(i_1), \dots g^{-1}(i_k),j}$$

The term $a$ is not actually defined exactly, but in light of the context I just think it could refer to the *set of all tensors of a certain rank $k$*. For example if we take $k =2$, then we have

$$X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n \times a}$$
Is it correct to interpret this as the *stack* of all possible $n \times n$ matrices?

Also, $j$ above is used to describe the *feature depth*, but I don't really understand why couoldn't we just leave $i_k$ as final index.